# Performance issue in hive version 0.13.1

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, hive, emr, amazon-ami

I use [AWS-EMR](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/UsingEMR_SupportedHiveVersions.html) to run my Hive queries and I have a performance issue while running hive version 0.13.1.

The newer version of hive took around 5 minutes for running 10 rows of data. But the same script for 230804 rows is taking 2 days and is still running. What should I do to analyze and fix the problem?

Sample Data:

**Table 1:**

```
hive> describe foo;
OK
orderno    string
Time taken: 0.101 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

> Sample data for table1:

```
hive>select * from foo;        
OK
1826203307
1826207803
1826179498
1826179657
```

**Table 2:**

```
hive> describe de_geo_ip_logs;
OK
id          bigint                                      
startorderno        bigint                                      
endorderno          bigint                                      
itemcode                int                                         
Time taken: 0.047 seconds, Fetched: 4 row(s)
```

> Sample data for Table 2:

```
hive> select * from bar;

127698025   417880320   417880575   306
127698025   3038626048  3038626303  584
127698025   3038626304  3038626431  269
127698025   3038626560  3038626815  163
```

**My Query:**

```
SELECT b.itemcode
FROM foo a,  bar b
WHERE a.orderno BETWEEN b.startorderno AND b.endorderno;
```

[image: Attached the hive logs for the above query.]

Comment: hive 0.13 is not stable and have lots of issues as many of the queries of older versions does not run in this version use latest hive 0.14

Comment: hive-0.14 have many advance features like  Insert,Update,Delete

Comment: This question is absurd.

Comment: post your hive query please.

Comment: @agarwal_achhnera Hive-0.14 support is still not available in AWS EMR.

Comment: @GoBrewers14 What is absurd, can you clarify if I am missing any data here. Your comments are not helping me to solve the problem.

Comment: @haosdent I have attached the Hive query now.

Comment: You original question said "I have a query, it runs slower in the new version." That was it.  How can you reasonably expect an answer to that question?  Looks like you've updated it.  Thank you.

Comment: hive join is inefficient but your query took too long in any way. did you get a chance to look into the hive query log files?

Comment: @zhutoulala I have attached hive log above.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the very top of your Hive log output, it states "Warning: Shuffle Join JOIN[4][Tables a, b] in Stage 'Stage-1 Mapred' is a cross product."

EDIT:
A 'cross product' or Cartesian product is a join without conditions, which returns every row in the 'b' table, for every row in the 'a' table. So, if you take an example of 'a' is 5 rows, and 'b' is 10 rows, you get the product, or, 5 multiplied by 10 = 50 rows returned. There will be a lot of rows that are completely 'null' for one or the other tables.

Now, if you have a table 'a' of 20,000 rows and join it to another table 'b' of 500,000 rows, you are asking the SQL engine to return to you a data set 'a, b' of 10,000,000,000 rows, and then perform the BETWEEN operation on the 10-million rows.

So, if you drop the number of 'b' rows, you see you will get more benefit than the 'a' - in your example, if you can filter the ip_logs table, table 2, since I am making a guess that it has more rows than your order number table, it will cut down on the execution time.
END EDIT

You're forcing the execution engine to work through a Cartesian product by not specifying a condition for the join. It's having to scan all of table a over and over. With 10 rows, you will not have a problem. With 20k, you are running into dozens of map/reduce waves.

Try this query:

```
 SELECT b.itemcode
 FROM foo a JOIN bar b on <SomeKey>
 WHERE a.orderno BETWEEN b.startorderno AND b.endorderno;
```

But I'm having trouble figuring out what column your model will allow joining on. Maybe the data model for this expression could be improved? It may just be me not reading the sample clearly.

Either way, you need to filter the number of comparisons BEFORE the where clause. Other ways I have done this in Hive is to make a view with a smaller set of data, and join/match the view instead of the original table.

Comment: Thanks @suiterdev.  I am using the above query without ON. It works for small data set with Warning: Map Join MAPJOIN[8][bigTable=b] in task 'Stage-3:MAPRED' is a cross product. But large set of data the query is running status.

Comment: I have edited my answer to provide more information, which I hope helps you understand the problem better.